# ESP8266 send GET request to remote server

Tags: php, esp8266, arduino-ide

http://www.universalcard.byethost7.com is my server. Where I kept index.php file. Code is as given below

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['pin']) && isset($_GET['cost'])) {

$username = $_GET['username'];
$pin = $_GET['pin'];
$cost = $_GET['cost'];
$filecontent = "Username is: ".$username." and PIN is: ".$pin." and cost is: ".$cost."\n";
$filestatus = file_put_contents('uc.txt',$filecontent,FILE_APPEND);
if($filestatus != false )
{
    echo "Data written to file..";
}else{
    echo "Ohh sorry..";
}

} else {
     echo "Something went wrong..";
}
?>
```

And I want to send a GET request from ESP8266 with Arduino IDE.
In this GET request, I am sending 3 variables 'username' , 'pin' and 'cost' with some values (data type is String). And these values are appending to a file "uc.txt". So when I send a request using a browser, values will append to the text file.

But when I tried to send using ESP8266 it is not appending

Arduino Code is below

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

const char* ssid = "rainbow";
const char* password = "12345678";

const char* host = "universalcard.byethost7.com";
const int httpsPort = 443;

// Use web browser to view and copy
// SHA1 fingerprint of the certificate
//const char* fingerprint = "CF 05 98 89 CA FF 8E D8 5E 5C E0 C2 E4 F7 E6 C3 C7 50 DD 5C";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Use WiFiClientSecure class to create TLS connection
  WiFiClientSecure client;
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);
  if (!client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

  String url = "/index.php?username=2bv14is114&pin=5555&cost=1111";
  Serial.print("requesting URL: ");
  Serial.println(url);

  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "User-Agent: BuildFailureDetectorESP8266\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

  Serial.println("request sent");
  while (client.connected()) {
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (line == "\r") {
      Serial.println("headers received");
      break;
    }
  }
  String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
  if (line.startsWith("{\"state\":\"success\"")) {
    Serial.println("esp8266/Arduino CI successfull!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("esp8266/Arduino CI has failed");
  }
  Serial.println("reply was:");
  Serial.println("==========");
  Serial.println(line);
  Serial.println("==========");
  Serial.println("closing connection");
}

void loop() {
}
```

And the output in Serial monitor is below

[image]

Comment: Your code says  `byethehost7.com` but your comments say `byethehost5.com` are you sending your request to the wrong site?

Comment: Yeah, a small mistake in question it should be universalcard.byethost7.com . And I will edit question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your host has some sort of protection (maybe against bots), that expects a `_test` cookie set by JavaScript, if not present.

You could acquire the cookie, by first visiting the site with the browser and copy paste the cookie into your code.
You would need to do it from the same IP, that your ESP8266 will be introduced to the server, since the cookie is IP bound.
In this case you would have a problem, if you have a dynamic IP and also the longevity of the cookie is unknown.

You could also acquire the cookie by parsing the response, but the cookie is AES encrypted and that would be somewhat complicated.

The most sensible solution would be to switch to a host without such protection.
This is a solution to basically the same problem in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056080/arduino-mega-esp-8266-sending-get-request) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771091/json-parse-error-on-line-1-html-body) question.

Comment: Yeah, it is problem with host. I tried with another hosting site www.hostinger.in and it worked fine.

Comment: 000webhostapp.com is another tested option